# HashLocationStrategy in Angular2 rc3 doesn't work

Tags: angular, routes

HashLocationStrategy in Angular2 rc3 doesn't work

```
import {provide} from '@angular/core';
import {LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from '@angular/common';
...
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    disableDeprecatedForms(),
    provideForms(),
    provide(LocationStrategy, { useClass: HashLocationStrategy }),
    APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS
]);
```

But the links are generated without #
I want to use a new router ("@angular/router": "3.0.0-alpha.7")

Answer (score 0):

Try with below configuration :

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    disableDeprecatedForms(),
    provideForms(),
    {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy},
    APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS
]);
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried the same thing.
Everything works, but the hash (#) not be inserted